# Typescript version dependent error for strongly referenced nested property names

Tags: typescript

The following code works for perfectly for typescript 4.2.4 however typescript 4.5.2 throws compile time error "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.ts(2589)".

All this code does is allows you to reference deeply nested property paths in a strongly typed way via dot notation and returns the path (assuming no compile time errors due to an invalid referenced path).

How can I modify this code to work with typescript 4.5.2?

```
type BigNumber = // bignumber definition
type Ignore<T> = Exclude<T, BigNumber>;
type Join<K, P> = K extends string | number ? P extends string | number ? `${K}${"" extends P ? "" : "."}${P}` : never : never;
type Prev = [never, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...0[]]
type DottedPaths<T, D extends number = 10> = [D] extends [never] ? 
    never 
: (
    T extends Array<infer TChild> ? (

        Ignore<TChild> extends never ? "" 
        :
            { 
                [K in keyof TChild] - ? : K extends string | number ? 
                    `${K}` | Join<K, DottedPaths<TChild[K], Prev[D]>>
                : never
                
            }[keyof TChild]
    ) 
    : 
    (
        Ignore<T> extends never ? ""
        :
            { 
                [K in keyof T] - ? : K extends string | number ?
                    `${K}` | Join<K, DottedPaths<T[K], Prev[D]>>
                : never

            }[keyof T] 
    )
);

interface IModel {
    propertyName: string;
    traits: {
        propertyName: string;
        trait: {
            propertyName: string;
        }
    }[];
    marketplace: {
        propertyName: string;
        secondaryPropertyName: string;
        traits: {
            propertyName: string;
            trait: {
                propertyName: string;
            }
        }[];
    }
}

const nameof = <TObject extends object>(name: DottedPaths<TObject>): string => <string>name;

interface IModel {
    propertyName: string;
    traits: {
        propertyName: string;
        trait: {
            propertyName: string;
        }
    }[];
    marketplace: {
        propertyName: string;
        secondaryPropertyName: string;
        traits: {
            propertyName: string;
            trait: {
                propertyName: string;
            }
        }[];
    }
}

nameof<IModel>('traits.trait.propertyName'); // 'traits.trait.propertyName'
nameof<IModel>('propertyName'); // 'propertyName'
nameof<IModel>('marketplace.traits.trait.propertyName'); // 'marketplace.traits.trait.propertyName'
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of TypeScript? I can't even reproduce the issue because the playground only goes as far back as version 3.3.3...

Comment: @vr. im an idiot, I updated OP with correct versions

Comment: I ended up with [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJAZDm) to get the dotted paths. There is some redundancy, yes, but when I tried to refactor it into a helper type, I got "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite" for some reason... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯